# how to create chat(websocket) server on google cloud platform

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, websocket, google-cloud-platform, chat

I already working on AppEngine which is my android backend but I have to create chat system for my app so I cannot figure out how to do that.
I'm using spring boot

please help. sorry for any kind of mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`google compute engine`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) on `google cloud` to write down your WebSocket server.

Also, you can use [apache thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) for a seamless design of communication protocol between different language. It saves lots of repeated effort while designing communication protocol.
From [Quora](https://www.quora.com/In-simple-terms-what-is-Thrift-software-framework-and-what-does-it-do)

> There's a lot of repeated work you have to do when you're writing a server - primarily designing a protocol and writing code to serialize and deserialize messages on the protocol, but also dealing with sockets and managing concurrency, and writing clients in many languages. Thrift automatically does all of this, given a description of the functions you want to expose from your server to clients. It's also useful for serializing data on disk or into shared memory (where many of the same problems come up).

Comment: is there any chance to run WebSocket server on app engine ??

Comment: I am not sure but most probably you can't.

Comment: spring boot application can run on Compute Engine stand alon

Comment: is there any tutorial that helps me

Comment: You can get a quick start for running [compute engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstarts) on google cloud and [documentation](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/) for apache thrift.

Comment: help me, bro, I have been using google cloud SQL for AppEngine and compute engine I installed SQL so can I use instead of cloud SQL  mean I consider to move on compute engine sql